# Ember-cli/blueprint POD structure for component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm working new with the ember-cli starter-kit and want to know whether it is possible to use the POD folder structure?

My goal is to have a "independent" component folder structure like this:

**component folder**

```
--index.hbs
--controller.hbs
--router.hbs
--style.css
--externaljavascripts.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know ember-cli supports the POD structure.

http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions

Scroll down to the POD section of the page.